# Constantly update a div's content to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div (.bx-caption) in which the text changes based on the title attribute of a selected image in a slider.

I'm trying to copy the text from this div to another div, and always have them be matching.

I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.screenTitle').html($(".bx-caption").html());
});
```

This code works to match the text when the site loads, but whenever I change images in the slider and .bx-caption switches to a new title, .screenTitle doesn't pick up on it and stays the same.

What can I do to ensure that .screenTitle always matches .bx-caption?

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps out.

Update: the HTML looks like this:

```
        <ul class="bxslider">
        <li><img src="images/1.png" title="Funky Roots" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/2.png" title="Little Toots" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/3.png" title="Epic Loots" /></li>
    </ul>       
</div>
<div class="outside">
    <div class="screenTitle"></div>
    <div id="slider-prev"></div> <div id="slider-next"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle trying to attempt the above:
[jsfiddle.net/uwA3Q/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/uwA3Q/2/)

Comment: Can you handle changing slide in your slider?

Comment: Can you post the HTML for this?

Comment: Call this script in the image rotation callback.

Comment: @LloydBanks The html looks like this.  It looked ugly in a comment, so I'm going to put it in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [bxslider](http://bxslider.com) add [onSlideAfter](http://bxslider.com/options#onSlideAfter) callback to change screen title:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    // ......
    onSlideAfter: function($slideElement) {
        // get .bx-caption element of current slide
        $('.screenTitle').html($slideElement.find('.bx-caption').html());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DQadF/2/

Comment: This almost works. Now after I click on the button to change the slide, .screenTitle updates once (to the first title), but nothing after that.

Comment: @javinladish As you can see `onSlideAfter` callback is called always after slide is changed. So, debug your code, try to add `alert` to this callback, and try to use function to get current slide http://bxslider.com/options#getCurrentSlide . Mabe it is easy to get current slide title

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DQadF/ You can see here in this JSFiddle trying to implement your solution. The title is able to change once, but only once. Can you help out please? I know we're close to solving this!

Answer (score 1):

Document.ready fires only once when you load the page.

who ever changing the slider put your code over there

```
$('.screenTitle').html($(".bx-caption").html());
```

for example if you have a click handler that changes the slide

```
$('#mySlide').on('click', function(){
   //do the changing of the slide
   //also update the title here
   $('.screenTitle').html($(".bx-caption").html());
})
```